# Import a Third Party Python Project without Adding It to sys.path

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import, python-importlib

I am trying to import a third party python 'project' in my own code. I am not referring it as a package because it seems to be prepared for running on its own but not for others to import it and run it somewhere else. For example, that third party project may look like this:

```
ProjectA/
|- utils/
  |- tools.py
|- lib/
  |- functions.py
|- main.py
```

and the dependency of files/functions goes like:

```
In main.py:
- from lib.functions import xxx

In lib/functions.py:
- from utils.tools import yyy
```

such that

1. running `main.py` requires the function `xxx` from `lib/functions.py`, and
2. running the function `xxx` in `lib/functions.py` requires the function `yyy` in `utils.tools.py`.

If I run `main.py` at the top level of Project A, both `lib` and `utils` are visible at this level so `main.py` runs successfully. Or, if I want to run the functions inside `main.py` somewhere else, I can add `path_to_ProjectA` to `sys.path` and everything runs well too.

However, there are occasions in which I prefer not to add this project to `sys.path`. For example, I might want to use another project `ProjectB` which also has a `utils` submodule, or I already have a `utils` submodule in my own project. In these cases, if I add both `ProjectA` and `ProjectB` to `sys.path`, then only one of `utils` submodules will get recognized (i.e., can be imported).

Therefore, I am wondering if there would be methods to make another's project available for importing. What I can think of is to make the project a 'legit' package, e.g., adding `__init__.py` at each level, changing the way to import packages/functions, etc. (Actually, I do not have much experience in doing this, and I do not have a clear idea about how too.) However, I do not believe this is always practical, especially when that project is sizeable and it may require fair understanding to the design of the project structure.

To summarize, my question is, what should I do so that I can import a third party python project outside that project without adding it to `sys.path`, even though that project is probably designed to be run only at its top directory level?

---

Edit #1 (20220819)

Following @Lenntror 's comments, I am adding a minimal example here. The goal is to call `ProjectA.lib.functions.xxx` from the outside of `ProjectA` without adding `ProjectA` to `sys.path`.

> (a) Calling `ProjectA.lib.functions.xxx` inside `ProjectA`

Structure of the third-party `ProjectA`:

```
ProjectA/
|-- lib
|   |-- __init__.py # Empty
|   `-- functions.py
|-- utils
    |-- __init__.py # Empty
    `-- tools.py
`-- main.py
```

Content of `ProjectA/lib/functions.py`:

```
from utils.tools import yyy

def xxx() :
    print("This is xxx().")
    print("Now xxx() calls yyy().")
    yyy()
```

Content of `ProjectA/utils/tools.py`:

```
def yyy() :
    print("This is yyy().")
```

Content of `ProjectA/main.py`:

```
from lib.functions import xxx

def main() :
    print("This is main().")
    print("Now calling xxx().")
    xxx()

if __name__=='__main__' :
    main()
```

If I run `python main.py` under the directory `ProjectA`. It works:

```
This is main().
Now calling xxx(). 
This is xxx().      
Now xxx() calls yyy().
This is yyy().
```

> (b) Calling `ProjectA.lib.functions.xxx` outside `ProjectA` by adding `ProjectA` to `sys.path`

Let's say, I have another folder `MyProject` which is next to (and outside) `ProjectA`:

```
./
|-- MyProject                                                               
|   `-- my_script.py    
|                                                    
`-- ProjectA
    |-- ...
```

Content of `MyProject/my_script.py`:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("../ProjectA")
from lib.functions import xxx

def main() :
    print("This is outside of ProjectA.")
    print("Now calling xxx().")
    xxx()

if __name__=='__main__' :
    main()
```

This also runs successfully:

```
This is outside of ProjectA.
Now calling xxx().
This is xxx().
Now xxx() calls yyy().
This is yyy().
```

> (c) Calling `ProjectA.lib.functions.xxx` by including `ProjectA` in a sub-directory/module

Now, I have a script in another folder also outside of `ProjectA`. This time, I include `ProjectA` inside this folder like this:

```
MyProject2/
|-- my_script.py
`-- thirdparty
    `-- ProjectA
        |-- ...
```

Content of `MyProject2/my_script.py`:

```
from thirdparty.ProjectA.lib.functions import xxx

def main() :
    print("This is outside of ProjectA.")
    print("Now calling xxx().")
    xxx()

if __name__=='__main__' :
    main()
```

This gives an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_script.py", line 1, in <module>
    from thirdparty.ProjectA.lib.functions import xxx
  File "/workspace/MyProject2/thirdparty/ProjectA/lib/functions.py", line 1, in <module>
    from utils.tools import yyy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'
```

Comment: Do I understand the question correctly: You have the .py files of Project A and want to run functions from its tools.py or functions.py modules in your own script? Without adding Project A to sys.path?

Comment: Been there! You should understand the design philosophy creators of python had in mind when creating the language. You should make ProjectA a package/module and have it everywhere inside the working directory. You could use some pacaking tools to make it a wheel package and install it everywhere you need.

Comment: @Nitish Thanks for your advice. I am learning to organize my project as python a package/module, as I believe its easier for others, and me also, to utilize the functions. However, in this case ```ProjectA``` is  created by someone else and its not designed in this way unfortunately. If I were to use some packaging tools to modify ```ProjectA```, would it be easy or would it still require much manual work to modify ```ProjectA``` to make it work?

Comment: @Lenntror Yes. For example, I want to use xxx in lib.functions in my own script somewhere outside ProjectA. If I do not add ProjectA to sys.path, when I call xxx it will attempt to do from utils.tools import yyy. However, utils is not visible at the location where I run my own script, and this results in a ModuleNotFoundError

Comment: Is it possible for you to just create a folder in your project called e.g. helpers and then put Project A inside that folder? That way you could import `from helpers.ProjectA.lib.functions`.

Comment: @Lenntror Unfortunately, only putting ```ProjectA``` inside a folder in my project is not enough. The same problem occurs: calling ```from lib.functions import xxx``` needs ```from utils.tools import yyy```, but I am at the outside of ```helpers```, so ```utils``` is not visible to me, hence the ```ModuleNotFoundError```.

Comment: Could you provide a link to such a project? I would like to try it myself

Comment: @Lenntror I edited my post and added an minimal example describing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So you could have the project file as this:

```
    ProjectA/
    |- utils/
      |- tools.py
    |- lib/
      |- functions.py
    |- main.py
    
    ProjectB/
    |- utils/
      |- tools.py
    |- lib/
      |- functions.py
    |- main.py

    your_project_file.py
```

`your_project_file.py` , `ProjectA` and `ProjectB` are sitting inside the same directory.

inside `your_project_file.py` you could use import statements like this:

`from ProjectA.lib.functions import xxx`

But I think you figured this out already that this will cause issue from `utils.tool`.
What you need to do, is use relative path. Edit `lib/functions.py` file and place a dot in front of `utils.tool` which should become `from .utils.tool import yyy`

Now it should resolve your problem and import in `your_project_file.py` should work fine. If not, then you need to define `__init__.py` file for all folders.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I believe this is a good practice and I will try this with my code. However, ```ProjectA``` in this situation is a third-party project, which has a lot of files and also lines of ```import``` code. This may not be practical if there is not a way to convert the code to use relative import.